# Adding Compilers On Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, compiler-construction, tcc

I have attempted to use the Netbeans IDE for C/C++.

Upon startup, I noticed that the only compiler chains it accepts are: MingGw, Cygwin, and Clang. My compiler is the latest version of TCC for win64.

Can I define my own compiler chain for netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you test `Tool Collection Family: Unknown`?

Go to **`Tools -> Options -> C/C++`** click **`Add`** and enter your path, the name and select `Unknown` as *family*. Possible you have to fix the paths or names of compilers etc. a bit.